# Opencv VideoCapture, not opening some video files

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, video, sdl

I'm trying to use the opencv librarie to display video files to the screen using sdl-2. I got it to work with smaller files(20.5Mb), but when i tryed using bigger files (100 and 136Mb) it didnt work and i go the message "ERROR: Coudnt load the video < video.avi>".

```
    cv::VideoCapture video;
    video.open(videoName);
    if (!video.isOpened())
    {
        SDL_Log("ERROR: Coudnt load the video <%s>", videoName.c_str());
        return;
    }
```

I don't know if size was the problem, but that would make the most sense to me. I've not found any documentation on size restrictions thought. Any ideas on how to fix it?

PS: All were .avi files, and the file's name was not the problem. Was able to open them with ffplay if that matters at all. OpenCV version 2.4.8

Comment: Which version of opencv are you using?

Comment: Updated answer with the version (2.4.8)